# How implement Pell number calculation in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate Pell numbers, however I am always ending up with `Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.` exception as the method is called recursively.

```
static int calcPell(int input)
{
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        if (input == 0 || input == 1)
            return input;
        else
            return i = (2 * calcPell(input - 1) + calcPell(input + 1));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: When is that function supposed to end if the original input is not 0 or 1? I'm not sure what you are doing there, but Pell numbers are a sequence, and you are not doing a sequence at all there.

Comment: At a glance it looks like this will recurse forever, you are always calling `calcPell(input + 1)` - the only time this won't fail is when you pass an input of 0 or 1

Comment: calcPell(input - 1) + calcPell(input + 1). One of these is always going down and the other is always going up. One of them will never reach 0 or 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number, should it be

```
return 2 * calcPell(input - 1) + calcPell(input -2);
```

Comment: Yes, input +1 is causing the endless recession.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm for calculating Pell numbers are not correct and it will not terminate if the provided input is greater than 1. Because your computer has limited resources it terminates with a stack overflow.

The problematic part is where `calcPell(int input)` calls `calcPell(input + 1)`. Calling `calcPell(2)` will call `calcPell(3)` which will call `calcPell(4)` and this continues indefinitely because only `calcPell(0)` and `calcPell(1)` will terminate the recursion.

In [the Wikipedia article about Pell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number) you can see the correct recurrence relation:

[image: Pell number recurrence relation]

In your implementation you have to fix the second return statement:

```
return 2 * calcPell(input - 1) + calcPell(input - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The program goes in infinite recursion as in this line

```
return i = (2 * calcPell(input - 1) + calcPell(input + 1));
```

the function call `calcPell(input + 1)` will be infinite as there is no upper limit defined